# Saving and incrementally updating nearest-neighbor model in R

Tags: r

There are several nearest neighbor R packages (e.g., FNN, RANN, yaImpute) but none of them seem to allow saving off the NN data structure (cover tree, KD tree etc.) so that the nearest neighbors of new queries can be calculated without reconstructing the whole tree. Are there any such functions in R?

I am looking for a function that returns a data structure that I can update incrementally as new  data arrives to perform approximate K nearest neighbor search.

Comment: I've looked around too, and I haven't found anything so far.  It sure seems like something should be out there though.

Comment: Can you provide a small example of which data you would like to be saved? Also if @KenWilliams could chip in.

Comment: Are there too many points to estimate the entire distance matrix?  If not, you should be able to find the distance matrix using the `spDists` function in the `sp` package then update the matrix as you get more data.

Comment: @Michael, actually I need a data structure that can be used to compute the nearest neighbors (and their distances) of a query point to a large (~10^6) target set of points. Usually this is done using space partitioning trees which take O(N log N) to build and O(log N) to query.  Unfortunately the query points are not all known ahead of time, which means that I need to save off the tree data structure created on the target set.

Comment: Innuo, If you can link to a mathematical description of the specific method you are facilitating, someone may be able to point out a useful package or to build the function for you.  As it stands, though, k-dimension trees and NN methods are both general concepts that can take many practical forms, and we need more specific info.  You may want to just take a look at the 'spdep' package and see if you can make some of those methods work for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good reason why no NN package does that.

The reason is that the "NN data structure" necessarily includes all the input data points (in the form of a [KD tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)), so there is no *space* savings against the input data. It appears that there would be *time* savings in not having to re-create the KD-tree for each new input, but this is not the case, alas.

The reason is that the time to build a KD-tree is, in general, **worse** than linearithmic. This means that, for large inputs, it makes sense to *sort* the data *before* building the KD-tree because that will produce the KD-tree faster and it will be better balanced, which will improve the search too (it is also worse than logarithmic, in general). This approach would speed up modeling and evaluation but discourage incremental updates, of course.

Your best bet, I think, if to find a generic [KD-tree package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/class/html/knn.html) and use it instead.

Comment: The data structure (KD-tree etc.) does include all the data points. However, the data structure is designed to enable efficient search. The point is that it would be beneficial to not have to recompute the data structure for every query.

Answer (score 0):

The nabor package lets you build a tree and subsequently perform queries on it. But I don't think it lets you update the tree incrementally.