# Updatable nearest neighbor search

Tags: scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to come up with a good design for a nearest neighbor search application. This would be somewhat similar to this question:

[Saving and incrementally updating nearest-neighbor model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202263/saving-and-incrementally-updating-nearest-neighbor-model-in-r)

In my case this would be in Python but the main point being the part that when new data comes, the model / index must be updated. I'm currently playing around with [scikit-learn neighbors module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) but I'm not convinced it's a good fit.

The goal of the application:

User comes in with a query and then the n (probably will be fixed to 5) nearest neighbors in the existing data set will be shown. For this step such a search structure from sklearn would help but that would have to be regenerated when adding new records.Also this is a first ste that happens 1 per query and hence could be somewhat "slow" as in 2-3 seconds compared to "instantly".

Then the user can click on one of the records and see that records nearest neighbors and so forth. This means we are now within the exiting dataset and the NNs could be precomputed and stored in redis (for now 200k records but can be expanded to 10th or 100th of millions). This should be very fast to browse around.

But here I would face the same problem of how to update the precomputed data without having to do a full recomputation of the distance matrix especially since there will be very few new records (like 100 per week).

Does such a tool, method or algorithm exist for updatable NN searching?

EDIT April, 3rd:

As is indicated in many places KDTree or BallTree isn't really suited for high-dimensional data. I've realized that for a Proof-of-concept with a small data set of 200k records and 512 dimensions, brute force isn't much slower at all, roughly 550ms vs 750ms.

However for large data set in millions+, the question remains unsolved. I've looked at datasketch LSH Forest but it seems in my case this simply is not accurate enough or I'm using it wrong. Will ask a separate question regarding this.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: when building efficient nearest neighbor structures such as a KD-tree, the "full" distance matrix is never computed (in the case of KD trees, arguably not even a partial one).

Comment: As your "new" data is such a small fraction of the "base" data, the arguably simplest (and for the forseeable future most performant) approach would be to have 2 nearest neighbour data structures, one for "base" and one for "new" and an adapter that hides the complexity of having 2 data structures. Inside the adapter, you then query both for your 5 neighbours and then do a brute force distance computation to find out which are your actual nearest neighbors.

Comment: At least for KD-trees, the fundamental problem that you are running into is that although adding to an existing tree is easy (and fast), over time this results in an unbalanced tree with worse look-up performance. As tree construction from scratch is fairly fast (something like O(n log n)), popular implementations such as the KDtree in `scipy.spatial` don't support addition of nodes after the initial construction (at some point the implementation in sklearn was just a wrapper around the one in scipy, not sure if that is still the case).

Comment: @Paul, yes rebalancing can become an issue in KD-Trees, but as long as the new data is fairly evenly distributed or the insertion rate is slow, the tree shouldn't get noticably imbalanced. Still, one alternative would be to recreate the tree every 1000 insertion or so, and some implementations even have a 'rebalancing' operation. Another alternative would be to use another tree such as an R*Tree (R-star-Tree) or simply a quadtree/octree/... (very fast up to 5 or 6 dimensions).

Comment: @TilmannZ I plan on using BallTree as algorithm within sklearn.NearestNeighbors because I have high dimensional data ( 512 dimensions, binary). But if there are better options for high dimensional data, that would also be a welcome suggestion. i have not seen how I can update the BallTree however after it's creation?

Comment: As far as I understand Balltrees, they are simply a way of loading a standard tree (such as KD-tree) in order to be more suitable for kNN-queries. This is usually achieved through bulk-loading (non-incremental loading), so I'm not sure there is an incremental way. Two remarks here: a) Doing a brief internet search, it looks like BallTrees are only marginally faster for kNN-qeries compared to nomal KD-Trees. b) R*Tree already group points for proximity, similar to a BallTree, so with R*Tree you get this BallTree-like grouping for free.

Comment: If you do some performance tests, could you post here whether BallTree is measurably faster than normal KD-Tree? (Loading is much slower, but kNN-queries may be faster). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TilmannZ I actually found this package through google and below blog posts from 2013 which as some performance stats. https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/04/29/benchmarking-nearest-neighbor-searches-in-python/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, the blog uses very small datasets and only few dimensions. I found also [this](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1210/1210.6122.pdf) (claiming that BalTree loading is very slow) and [this](https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks) for approximate nearest neighbors. [Here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin/blob/master/doc/benchmark-2017-01/Diagrams.pdf) are my own tests with 1'000'000 points and up to 40 dimensions (kNN is in Figures 32-35).

Answer (score 3):

You should look into FAISS and its IVFPQ method
What you can do there is create multiple indexes for every update and merge them with the old one

Comment: IVFPQ does support incremental indexing, so multiple indexes are not needed.

Answer (score 3):

You could try out [Milvus](https://milvus.io/) that supports adding and near real-time search of vectors.

Here are the [benchmarks](https://milvus.io/docs/benchmarks_azure) of Milvus.

Answer (score 1):

[nmslib](https://github.com/nmslib/nmslib) supports adding new vectors. It's used by OpenSearch as part their [Similarity Search Engine](https://opensearch.org/blog/odfe-updates/2020/04/Building-k-Nearest-Neighbor-(k-NN)-Similarity-Search-Engine-with-Elasticsearch/), and it's [very fast](https://pub.towardsai.net/knn-k-nearest-neighbors-is-dead-fc16507eb3e).

One caveat:

> While the HNSW algorithm allows incremental addition of points, it forbids deletion and modification of indexed points.

You can also look into solutions like [Milvus](https://milvus.io/docs/overview.md) or [Vearch](https://github.com/vearch/vearch).